# getting error message: name 'a' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

```
def sum(a, b, c, d):
    result = 0
    result = result+a+b+c+d
    return result


def length():
    return 4


def mean(a, b, c, d):
    return float(sum(a, b, c, d))/length()


print(sum(a, b, c, d), length(), mean(a, b, c, d))
```

I am getting the error message `name 'a' is not defined`

Comment: Have you defined `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t define the variable you’ll gonna get these name errors.  Let’s say for example you switch the values when you call these functions -

```
print(sum(a, b, c, d), length(), mean(a, b, c, d))
```

Here, in this case you’ll gonna get `name b is not defined` because Python interpreter doesn’t know what’s the value that variable `b` is storing.

You need to tell the interpreter what are the values for these variables.

`For example -  a=10, b=2,.. and so on`

Answer (score 0):

**a variable is undefined** means that you need to define **(assign a value)** to that variable. For example, `a=1` should work.